# Insulation in exposed beam kitchen restoration

Tags: insulation, ceiling

I live in a Philadelphia row home and suffered a fire about 7 months ago. My whole house had to be restored due to smoke damage.

During the demo, I noticed the beams in the kitchen extension on the house and asked the contractors if they could leave them exposed. I was under the impression that they would put some type of insulation under the sheetrock, but instead, they just used 2 layers of 5/8" sheetrock between the beams. When I asked if that was adequate, they said it was just fine and that if I wanted any more insulation, I would have to lose the beams. There is nothing above the kitchen but roof.

Here are some pictures after the demo and after sheetrock was added.
https://imgur.com/a/eARdTvX

[image: ceiling after demo]

[image: Ceiling after sheetrock]

*click images for full size*

My contractors have been doing a sloppy job, and frankly, I don't trust them any longer.
I'm hoping someone here could tell me what the right way to do this is or if it is even advisable to keep the beams exposed in this situation. let me know if I left out any important info.

Comment: I sure hope that wiring is only temporary...

Comment: Communication was poor in this instance. You got what you asked for. The contractor should have advised that there would be very little insulation factor.  Never assume.

Comment: @RMDman You are right. Terrible communication but I found a text where he said he could put insulation under the sheetrock. He's saying now that his idea of insulation was another layer of sheetrock. Sounds like BS.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing above them is roof - so insulate the roof. You can insulate on top of the present waterproof membrane (if you are careful not to damage it while insulating) or you can insulate and add a new waterproof membrane. In either case the typical insulation would be XPS foam or something similar. If it's a low-slope roof as common for that type of building that may get walked on a common product is a sandwich of cementboard on top of foam (the cementboard keeps the foam from blowing away and provides damage resistance.)

If you can find a contractor there's also spray polyurethane foam as both insulation and waterproofing (with some additional layer for UV protection, IIRC - but I can't find a contractor that does roofs with sprayfoam in my area.)

Comment: They say adding insulation to the roof is totally out of scope. This is being paid for through my insurance, so I'm trying not to go out of bounds right now.

They also claim that two layers of sheetrock should be fine, not cold and that it's not much different from what I originally had. 

Does this sound totally wrong to you all? Would you insulate and lose the beams?